# Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I am calling two api call in single page. but if i use one api call its working fine. But if i use two api call in same page. I'm getting below error at Runtime.

> Error Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found`.

And i have one doubt too. Where ever i go to any screens. If i want to come back to my home screen. I need to show the Api called Data to display always. So should i need to call my Api call method inside constructor or `ionViewDidEnter`. i did in `ionViewDidEnter` i don't things show this may be the causes for my error.

***Here is my code :***

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, App, FabContainer, ItemSliding, List, ModalController, NavController, ToastController, LoadingController, Refresher } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CategoryDetailPage } from '../categorydetail/categorydetail';
import { ConferenceData } from '../../providers/conference-data';
import { UserData } from '../../providers/user-data';
import { SessionDetailPage } from '../session-detail/session-detail';
import { ScheduleFilterPage } from '../schedule-filter/schedule-filter';
import {Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/AuthService';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-speaker-list',
  templateUrl: 'speaker-list.html'
})

export class SpeakerListPage {
   loading: any;
   data: any;
   Catdata: any;
   Catdatanames: any;
   resdata: any;
   resCatdata: any;
   resCatdatanames: any;
   loginData: {username?: string} = {};
   resloginData: {username?: string} = {};

  constructor(
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public app: App,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public modalCtrl: ModalController,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public confData: ConferenceData,
    public user: UserData,
    public http:Http,
    public authService: AuthService) { }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
   this.show();
   this.another();
  }

  show() {
    this.showLoader();
      this.authService.subs(this.loginData).then((result) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      this.data = result;

       if(this.data.status == 1)
       {
           this.Catdata = this.data.SubjectList;
           for(let i=0; i<this.Catdata.length; i++) {
               console.log(this.Catdata[i].SubjectName);
           }
       }
       else if(this.data.status == 0) {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'Error',
              subTitle: 'Please Enter Valid Username & Password',
              buttons: ['OK']
          });
          alert.present();
       }
    }, (err) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
    });
}

another() {
  this.showLoader();
    this.authService.allresources(this.resloginData).then((result) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      this.resdata = result;

      if(this.resdata.status == 1)
      {
           this.resCatdata = this.resdata.SubjectList;
           for(let i=0; i<this.resCatdata.length; i++) {
               console.log(this.resCatdata[i].FileName);
           }
      }
      else if(this.resdata.status == 0) {
         let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Error',
            subTitle: 'Please Enter Valid Username & Password',
            buttons: ['OK']
         });
         alert.present();
       }
    }, (err) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
    });
}

showLoader(){
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Authenticating...'
    });
    this.loading.present();
  }
}
```

Please help me out. How can solve my issue?

***My ionic info***:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.5
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.3.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

Help will be much useful.Thanks

Comment: if you are using loading then try to comment it on this page and try with two get calls itself

Comment: @MohanGopi  sorry i din get you.i am ew to ionic. can u explain me what should i do

Comment: you are using `this.loading.present();` and`this.loading.dissmiss()` in your 
 Api call comment that part and try

Comment: oh i need to comment the loading part. Okay.will try. but when i want the data to show whenever i come this screen. should i need to call that two method inside constructor or under `ionViewDidEnter`

Comment: it depends upon your requirement

Comment: requirement ??. not like that for me. if i some screens. and again if i come that home screen. i need the api called and the data have to diaplay always. so should i need to put under constructor or `ionViewDidEnter`

Comment: @MohanGopi  now i am getting new error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined `.. under my api call method.

Comment: did your check your api call in post man i think `this.Catdata.length;` is error check in post man what do you get and check the Catdata array is correctly assigned or not

Comment: `this.Catdata.length ` no parameters like length. ist the for loop that i got solution from stack overflow. here that solution given like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800137/how-to-call-object-value-ionic-2

Comment: make your api calls in constructor itself after navigating to next and returning back is not able do the api call the move the api call in ionviewdidenter

Comment: ok check it in postman and let me know

Comment: i have checked. only `    "CatID": "13",
      "CategoryName": "Plant Physiology",
      "CategoryStatus": "Active"` is available like 10 datas

Comment: @MohanGopi  i din get you about the `make your api calls in constructor itself after navigating to next and returning back is not able do the api call the move the api call in ionviewdidenter` this message. ........ after navigating to next pages adn returing to home pages will not call the api call. So its better to do that api call method under `constructor` . let me know if i got your point correctly ??

Comment: ok tell me one thing if you navigate to another page and come back to the previous page what you are getting

Comment: some times its showing the data some times not if i put in constructor or under `ionviewdidload` i tried. thast why asked which one is need to do under constructor or `ionviewdidload` or `ionViewDidEnter`

Comment: And that length error i am getting . and there is one test close at top `run time error`. if i press close . my data are showing in screen. but i dont know why i am getting that error when i run

Comment: `ionViewDidEnter` will always all the api when ever you vist the page

Comment: thanks, now what should i need to do for my length error. any solution please

Comment: comment the show() funtion and then check if you are ok the comment the another() function and check that will let you know which is making the error

Comment: @MohanGopi  you are right in my `another()` its making the issue.i also posted my `another()` method api call json data output from my db. what ia m wrong really not able to identify

Comment: ask new question related to your error so that you will get a clear answer

Comment: @MohanGopi   can u help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819687/data-are-not-showing-when-two-api-called-in-iondidenter

Comment: did you manage to solve the "Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found" error? I am having the same and I don't know how to resolve.

Comment: @SamirBoulos   if you have two methods or two api call methods. And if you use some loading controller or any loader . Try to make it as one loader for all method calling

Comment: Want to note that this happened to me with dismissOnPageChange and a manual dismiss.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question asked more than a month ago!

I was going through the same scenario with same problem and i sorted out this issue.

And i have posted the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828359/ionic-error-uncaught-in-promise-removeview-was-not-found/44515433#44515433) in another stackoverflow [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828359/ionic-error-uncaught-in-promise-removeview-was-not-found).

Some of the [discussion and reference](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11443) available to get know the issue.

> ***Note:*** If you call this.loading.dismiss() manually, I don't recommend to use dismissOnPageChange, you are probably dismissing the
>   same loading twice.
>
> I think this.loading.present() is asynchronous method., So we can't
>   call this.loading.dismiss() manually when this.loading.present() is
>   still running.
>
> So if we need to dismiss manually we need to make sure that loading is
>   presented and have a view to dismiss it, we should use other method
>   after present().then like my code in below.

```
    public searchClick() {
       this.createLoader();
       this.loading.present().then(() => {
       this.searchService.submitRequest(params, data)
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.loading.dismiss(); // Dismissing the loader manually.
                //Call the other function
                //You can dismiss loader here 
                //You can dismiss loader in other functions too by calling it from here, Since the scope will be available to that also.
            }, error => {
              this.loading.dismiss();
              this.errorMessage = <any>error
            });
      });
   }

   createLoader(message: string = "Please wait...") { // Optional Parameter
      this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: message
   });
 }
```

I hope this helps you out/gives you idea about your problem, if you still have the issue.

[Ionic Framework ***LoadingController*** Documentation for this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/).

Answer (score 1):

**Cause of issue:** *There are multiple calls to dismiss method of loading component.*

**Solution:**
While creating the loader, check if the loader instance is **not** **already present**, only then create another instance.

Similarly, while dismissing the loader, check if the loader instance **does exists**, only then dismiss it.

**Code:**

```
constructor(private _loadingCtrl: LoadingController){}

loading;

showLoading() {
    if(!this.loading){
        this.loading = this._loadingCtrl.create({
            content: 'Please Wait...'
        });
        this.loading.present();
    }
}

dismissLoading(){
    if(this.loading){
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.loading = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the following by using this method.

```
this.loading.dismissAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error which was caused by accidentally having two handlers firing. One was part of the form as an ngSubmit attribute, the other one was on a custom save button. Removing one of the two solved it.