# Ionic - Error: Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view, ionic3

My Ionic app was working fine and I haven't done anything to it but suddenly I am getting this error and I don't know why.

> "Error: Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When you want to manually dismiss the Ionic loading you may need to follow the below example. Which is working fine I have tested in ionic labs.

```
Ionic 3+
```

***Note:***
If you call this.loading.dismiss() manually, I don't recommend to use dismissOnPageChange, you are probably dismissing the same loading twice.

*Why the below solution works?*

I think `this.loading.present()` is an asynchronous method, so we can't call `this.loading.dismiss()` manually when `this.loading.present()` is still running.

So if we need to dismiss manually we need to make sure that loading is present already and have a view to dismiss it, we should use other method after `present().then` like the following code.

However I'm not sure why we didn't have this problem in the old framework version (2.0.3).

```
import { Loading, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class ApnSearchPage {
   loading: Loading;
   constructor(private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }

   ionViewDidLoad() {
     this.createLoader();
   }

   createLoader(message: string = "Please wait...") { // Optional Parameter
     this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
       content: message
     });
   }

   public searchClick() {
       this.createLoader();
       this.loading.present().then(() => {
       this.searchService.submitRequest(params, data)
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.loading.dismiss();
            }, error => {
              this.loading.dismiss();
              this.errorMessage = <any>error
            });
      });
   }
}
```

[Reference Link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11443),hence posted only useful and working tips and code.

I hope this helps!

Comment: But it still throws error "removeView was not found".. i am also using the confirm prompt.. is that causing error???

Answer (score 56):

Deleting a component is **not** a solution to any problem.

**Cause of issue:** *There are multiple calls to dismiss method of loading component.*

**Solution:**
While creating the loader, check if the loader instance is **not** **already present**, only then create another instance.

Similarly, while dismissing the loader, check if the loader instance **does exists**, only then dismiss it.

**Code:**

```
constructor(private _loadingCtrl: LoadingController){}

loading;

showLoading() {
    if(!this.loading){
        this.loading = this._loadingCtrl.create({
            content: 'Please Wait...'
        });
        this.loading.present();
    }
}

dismissLoading(){
    if(this.loading){
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.loading = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using two types of controller.. one is loading controller and the other one is AlertController, i tried this code but it still throws an error "removeView was not found".. What can be the problem???

Comment: I enhanced it to include pseudo reference counting to not remove throbber early if multiple operations are requesting it

Comment: do we need to use the "create()" inside every pages we make in ionic? Can't we make a global provider and just make two function like show() and hide()?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that I had

```
dismissOnPageChange: true
```

when I created the loadingCtrl.

The .dismiss() was being called too soon after the .present() (during local testing the api responds really fast) and it seems having that parameter caused the issue. Removing it solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the simple fix was changing:

```
this.loader.dismiss()
```

to:

```
this.loader.dismiss().then(value => {
    console.log("dismiss worked!");
}, reason => {
    console.log("dismiss rejected!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by deleting the LoadingController from my component.

Comment: how did u delete it?

Comment: This is not an answer. The correct answer is above.

Comment: Deleting is not a solution to ay question.

Comment: This is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

I removed loading.dismiss function and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

it says that you called to loading.dismiss() before load.presenet() ended. 
you should try

```
let a = this.loadingCtrl.create({content : 'hello world'})
await a.present();
..
.. // your code goes here..
...
a.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one for the alertController but works very similar.

```
logout() {
  let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Logout',
    subTitle: 'Are You Sure You Want To Logout?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'No',
        handler: data => {
          let navTransition = prompt.dismiss();
           navTransition.then(() => {
             this.navCtrl.pop();
           });
         return false;
       }

     },
     {
       text: 'Yes',
       handler: data => {
         this.lgout();
       }
     }
   ]
  });
 prompt.present();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simplest solution to this problem:

I have got this problems when implementing the **LoadingController**

**Note: Don't initialize loader inside the construction** (it works only first time and from second time you will get stuck with remove view not found problem)

```
loading:any;

this.loading=this.loadingCtrl.create({
        spinner:'bubbles',
        content:`Please wait..`
      });
```

I was displaying the loader while getting data from server
Below is the working code

```
 gosignup(number:string){

    this.loading.present();//showing the loader
    //calling webservice 
    this.Authprovider.smsverify(number).subscribe(
      data=>{                  
        this.loading.dismiss();//to dismiss loader        
        if(data.json().msg=="success"){
           this.navCtrl.push(SignupPage,{
             user:this.Usersignup
           })
        }

        if(data.json().msg=="error"){
          this.showToastWithCloseButton("Invalid otp");
        }

      },

      err=>{
          this.loading.dismiss();
          this.showToast("Please try again later");
      },

      ()=>{
              this.loading.dismiss();//to dismiss loader
      }

      );



  }
```

Hope it will solve SO problems

Comment: My code does not execute that last block at all so my loader just stays there without getting dismissed

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below which worked for me

```
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';
export class PopoverPage {
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController
     , public viewCtrl: ViewController
    , public appCtrl: App) {
         this.viewCtrl.dismiss().then(()=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{
            confirm.dismiss().then(()=>{
              this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot('DashboardPage');
            })
          },300)
        })
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated to the latest version @ionic/app-scripts 3.3.0 and this is also happening in my app.