# Ionic - Error: Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found on pressing browser back button in ionic 3 PWA

Tags: ionic3

In my Ionic 3 PWA, everything is fine apart from an issue.
If I navigated to some page from root page through other pages, then press browser back button, I receive

**Ionic - Error: Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found**

issue & it directly jumps to root page. If I press navbar back everything is good, navigating pages back one by one. 
Similar issue reported but those are not related to browser back button. Though I tried all those (e.g. loadingController dismiss, alertCtrl dismiss etc.), but no luck.
I am using tabs at root page and lazy loading with IonicPage decorator.

Comment: checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828359/ionic-error-uncaught-in-promise-removeview-was-not-found ?

Comment: Yes @SurajRao. Already checked. No success. I am getting this only when I press browser back.