# Data are not showing when two api called in` iondidenter`

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I have one screen, which have two gridview . each grid view will populate some value after api calling. so my page will have 2 api calling. so when i call my api call method under constructor or `ionViewDidEnter` its not working. it allowing only one method to exeute.

here is my two api call method on one **page .ts**

Even i put under my constructor. But its not showing the data. so if i want to call the both api and need to display the data means how can i do that.please help me out. i was not able to find it out !!

Thanks in advance

**updated:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, App, FabContainer, ItemSliding, List, ModalController, NavController, ToastController, LoadingController, Refresher } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CategoryDetailPage } from '../categorydetail/categorydetail';
import { ConferenceData } from '../../providers/conference-data';
import { UserData } from '../../providers/user-data';
import { SessionDetailPage } from '../session-detail/session-detail';
import { ScheduleFilterPage } from '../schedule-filter/schedule-filter';
import {Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/AuthService';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-speaker-list',
  templateUrl: 'speaker-list.html'
})
export class SpeakerListPage {
loading: any;

   data: any;
   Catdata: any;
   Catdatanames: any;


    resdata: any;
   resCatdata: any;
   resCatdatanames: any;


   loginData: {username?: string} = {};
   resloginData: {username?: string} = {};


  constructor(
     public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public app: App,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public modalCtrl: ModalController,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public confData: ConferenceData,
    public user: UserData,
    public http:Http,
    public authService: AuthService
  ) { 


  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.show(); 
  this.another();
  }


show() {
  this.showLoader();

    this.authService.subs(this.loginData).then((result) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      this.data = result;

       if(this.data.status == 1)
       {
       this.Catdata = this.data.SubjectList;

       //this.Catdata.forEach(category => console.log(category.CatID));

      for(let i=0; i<this.Catdata.length; i++) {
              // console.log(this.Catdata[i].SubjectName);
           } 

       }

       else if(this.data.status == 0) {

     let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Error',
    subTitle: 'Please Enter Valid Username & Password',
    buttons: ['OK']
  });
  alert.present();
       }

    }, (err) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();

    });
}


another() {

    this.authService.allresources(this.resloginData).then((result) => {


      this.resdata = result;

       if(this.resdata.status == 1)
       {
       this.resCatdata = this.resdata.SubjectList;
           for(let i=0; i<this.resCatdata.length; i++) {
              // console.log(this.resCatdata[i].FileName);
           }



       }

       else if(this.resdata.status == 0) {

     let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Error',
    subTitle: 'Please Enter Valid Username & Password',
    buttons: ['OK']
  });
  alert.present();
       }

    }, (err) => {


    });
}

showLoader(){
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Authenticating...'
    });

    this.loading.present();
  }



}
```

Comment: what is logindata and reslogindata? also which api is not working and are you sure its not server side issue?

Comment: yes, i can print the data. that `logindata` and `reslogindata` are the parameter to pass to get the data from api. and if i put my api calling method seperately under `ionViewDidEnter` its working adn showing the data. so no server side issue.

Comment: @suraj  i dont know its break my head. dont know why 2 api calling ,method are not taking ??

Comment: they dont look dependant on each other.. can you show the whole component file?

Comment: @suraj  done.please check at bro.and please give me some solution

Comment: where are the two parameters set? you are sending empty object?

Comment: that two parameters is for sake. if we pass or not pass also it will show the data. like that only api db has written. i checked with postman. if i send any parameter or no parameter also its working fine. i think the problme is some wr

Comment: no errors in the console or network tab?

Comment: No, i din get any

Comment: @suraj  is my code is fine, any other misyake i done

Comment: should it go to if in both responses?

Comment: @suraj  sorry i don get u

Comment: i meant should it show alert in both cases?

Comment: i din try that. but i try comment one method and show other method. like that i tried. its working seperately .but both not working ata a time

Comment: you will have to put some console logs and debug..

Comment: even i did that. i put console at starting of each method code. in my `ionviewdidenter` if i put my first api calling method that only executing. no console message for my second method

Comment: oh my god. bro now i put console. now i am getting the two console message. but i dont know why data alone not showing if i put same. but data is showing if i put seperately

Comment: `(err) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();

    }` put log here.. log your errors

Comment: no error i am getting bro. i even tried removing loader and all. but still its not showing the data

Comment: @suraj  but its going inside the two api calling method. but not shwoing data